# Utility Method Returning Different Type (Set instead of List)

Tags: apex, sobject, set, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

Previously I had posted this question awhile back: [Utility Methods flexible enough for all sObject Types](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/utility-methods-flexible-enough-for-all-sobject-types)

Now I want to expand my method a bit to return a `Set<Object>` instead of a `List<Object>`

**Here is the original method:**

```
public static List<Object> getValuesByField (Type listType, List<SObject> records, SObjectField field){
    List<Object> results = (Object[])listType.newInstance();
    for(SObject record: records) {
        results.add(record.get(field));
    }
    return results;
}
```

**I use this method like so:** *(works just fine)*

```
List<String> zip_codes = (List<String>) Utils.getValuesByField(List<String>.class, accounts, Account.ShippingPostalCode);
```

**But now if I need a Set (unique list) I have this overloaded method:**

```
public static Set<Object> getValuesByField (Type listType, List<SObject> records, SObjectField field, Boolean isSet){
    List<Object> result_list = (Object[])listType.newInstance();
    for(SObject record: records) {
        result_list.add(record.get(field));
    }
    Set<Object> results = new Set<Object>(result_list);
    return results;
}
```

**And attempt to use it like so:**

```
Set<String> zip_codes = (Set<String>) Utils.getValuesByField(Set<String>.class, accounts, Account.ShippingPostalCode, true);
```

**I get the following error:**

> Incompatible types since an instance of `Set<Object>` is never an instance of `Set<String>`

Any thoughts?

Comment: My interpretation is that in place of a mechanism designed to allow code to be written ones for many types  - e.g. [generics in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) - a few special cases have been allowed in Apex for lists but these aren't a general feature hence the problem you have run into. So it looks like for sets you will always have to use explicit types e.g. `Set<String> zip_codes = new Set<String>((List<String>) Utils.getValuesByField(...));`. Bottom line is limit your ambitions when using Apex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's all sorts of dodgy ways to do this, but I find that the easiest is to simply use an "out-parameter," because then you don't even need to worry about casting. It works like this:

```
public static void getValuesByField (Set<Object> results, List<SObject> records, SObjectField field){
    for(SObject record: records) {
        results.add(record.get(field));
    }
}
```

Since objects always pass-by-reference, all you need to do is make sure your set is initialized beforehand.

Edit:

In fact, this is similar to a function that's included in my (soon-to-be-released) OSS library I'm writing:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Get many values from many records at once
public static void get(SObject[] sources, SObjectField field, Object[] values) {
    for(SObject source: sources) {
        values.add(source.get(field));
    }
}
```

It's still not "developed" enough to be released yet, though. I'll announce it on more formal channels when it is.

Edit #2 (from comments)

You can always cast from an Object to a Set (assuming the rules are met), so you can, for example:

```
public static Object getValuesByField (Type resultType, List<SObject> records, SObjectField field, Boolean isSet) {
    Set<Object> results = new Set<Object>();
    for(SObject record: records) {
        results.add(record.get(field));
    }
    return JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(results), resultType);
}
```

Comment: Sad to have to do that but good to know it's a possibility.

Comment: I have a couple instances where I do this exact thing, but for this method the casting isn't a big deal, I like being able to use it with one line. Can you also show what would be the other way without the "out-parameter"

Comment: @Xtremefaith Behold. Hacks at their best.

Comment: shouldn't the out parameter in the first example be named `result_set` or maybe, just `results` ? (as type of parameter is a set, not a list)

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for mentioning that. I'm not sure why they were named that, but I've changed them to just "results", which is one of several values I'd prefer to use.

Comment: actually, I'm not sure your example 1 even is callable as sets of primitive types are never `set<Object>` - at least as per compile errors I get

Comment: @cropredy, yes I have the same error message on compiling

Answer (score 1):

You may be reinventing the wheel. I believe what you're looking for already exists in the `SetUtils Class` of the [ApexLang Repo](https://github.com/bruceyue/ApexLang) on GitHub. I think the `pluckString` methods may be along the lines of what you're looking for. See the code below.

```
/* ============================================================
 * This code is part of the "apex-lang" open source project avaiable at:
 * 
 *      http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/
 *
 * This code is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.  You may obtain a 
 * copy of the License at:
 * 
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * ============================================================
 */
global class SetUtils {

    global static Set<Blob> objectToBlob(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Blob> blobSet = new Set<Blob>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Blob){
                blobSet.add((Blob)anObject);
            }
        }
        return blobSet;
    }

    global static Set<Boolean> objectToBoolean(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Boolean> booleanSet = new Set<Boolean>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Boolean){
                booleanSet.add((Boolean)anObject);
            }
        }
        return booleanSet;
    }

    global static Set<Date> objectToDate(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Date> dateSet = new Set<Date>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Date){
                dateSet.add((Date)anObject);
            }
        }return dateSet;
    }

    global static Set<Datetime> objectToDatetime(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Datetime> datetimeSet = new Set<Datetime>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Datetime){
                datetimeSet.add((Datetime)anObject);
            }
        }
        return datetimeSet;
    }

    global static Set<Decimal> objectToDecimal(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Decimal> decimalSet = new Set<Decimal>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Decimal){
                decimalSet.add((Decimal)anObject);
            }
        }
        return decimalSet;
    }

    global static Set<Double> objectToDouble(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Double> doubleSet = new Set<Double>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Double){
                doubleSet.add((Double)anObject);
            }
        }return doubleSet;
    }

    global static Set<ID> objectToID(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<ID> idSet = new Set<ID>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof ID){
                idSet.add((ID)anObject);
            }
        }
        return idSet;
    }

    global static Set<Integer> objectToInteger(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Integer> integerSet = new Set<Integer>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Integer){
                integerSet.add((Integer)anObject);
            }
        }
        return integerSet;
    }

    global static Set<Long> objectToLong(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Long> longSet = new Set<Long>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Long){
                longSet.add((Long)anObject);
            }
        }
        return longSet;
    }

    global static Set<Time> objectToTime(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Time> timeSet = new Set<Time>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof Time){
                timeSet.add((Time)anObject);
            }
        }
        return timeSet;
    }

    global static Set<String> objectToString(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<String> stringSet = new Set<String>();
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(anObject instanceof String){
                stringSet.add((String)anObject);
            }
        }
        return stringSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> blobToObject(Set<Blob> blobSet){
        if(blobSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Blob aBlob : blobSet){
            objectSet.add(aBlob);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> booleanToObject(Set<Boolean> booleanSet){
        if(booleanSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Boolean aBoolean : booleanSet){
            objectSet.add(aBoolean);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> dateToObject(Set<Date> dateSet){
        if(dateSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Date aDate : dateSet){
            objectSet.add(aDate);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> datetimeToObject(Set<Datetime> datetimeSet){
        if(datetimeSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Datetime aDatetime : datetimeSet){
            objectSet.add(aDatetime);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> decimalToObject(Set<Decimal> decimalSet){
        if(decimalSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Decimal aDecimal : decimalSet){
            objectSet.add(aDecimal);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> doubleToObject(Set<Double> doubleSet){
        if(doubleSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Double aDouble : doubleSet){
            objectSet.add(aDouble);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> idToObject(Set<ID> idSet){
        if(idSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(ID aID : idSet){
            objectSet.add(aID);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> integerToObject(Set<Integer> integerSet){
        if(integerSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Integer aInteger : integerSet){
            objectSet.add(aInteger);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> longToObject(Set<Long> longSet){
        if(longSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Long aLong : longSet){
            objectSet.add(aLong);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> timeToObject(Set<Time> timeSet){
        if(timeSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(Time aTime : timeSet){
            objectSet.add(aTime);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static Set<Object> stringToObject(Set<String> stringSet){
        if(stringSet == null){
            return null;    
        }
        Set<Object> objectSet = new Set<Object>();
        for(String aString : stringSet){
            objectSet.add(aString);
        }
        return objectSet;
    }

    global static String toString(Set<Blob> blobSet){ return toString(blobToObject(blobSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Boolean> booleanSet){ return toString(booleanToObject(booleanSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Date> dateSet){ return toString(dateToObject(dateSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Datetime> datetimeSet){ return toString(datetimeToObject(datetimeSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Decimal> decimalSet){ return toString(decimalToObject(decimalSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Double> doubleSet){ return toString(doubleToObject(doubleSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<ID> idSet){ return toString(idToObject(idSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Integer> integerSet){ return toString(integerToObject(integerSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Long> longSet){ return toString(longToObject(longSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<Time> timeSet){ return toString(timeToObject(timeSet)); }
    global static String toString(Set<String> stringSet){ return toString(stringToObject(stringSet)); }

    global static String toString(Set<Object> objectSet){
        if(objectSet == null){
            return 'null';
        }
        if(objectSet.size() <= 0){
            return '{}';
        }
        String returnValue = '';
        Boolean isFirst = true;
        for(Object anObject : objectSet){
            if(isFirst){
                isFirst = false;    
            } else {
                returnValue += ',';
            }
            if(anObject instanceof Blob){ returnValue += '\'' + ((Blob)anObject).toString() + '\'';
            } else if(anObject instanceof Boolean){ returnValue += ((Boolean)anObject);
            } else if(anObject instanceof Date){ returnValue += '\'' + ((Date)anObject) + '\'';
            } else if(anObject instanceof Datetime){ returnValue += '\'' + ((Datetime)anObject) + '\'';
            } else if(anObject instanceof Integer){ returnValue += ((Integer)anObject);
            } else if(anObject instanceof Long){ returnValue += ((Long)anObject);
            } else if(anObject instanceof Decimal){ returnValue += ((Decimal)anObject);
            //} else if(anObject instanceof Double){ returnValue += ((Double)anObject);
            } else if(anObject instanceof String){ returnValue += '\'' + ((String)anObject) + '\'';
            //} else if(anObject instanceof ID){ returnValue += '\'' + ((ID)anObject) + '\'';
            } else if(anObject instanceof Time){ returnValue += '\'' + ((Time)anObject) + '\'';}
        }
        return '{' + returnValue + '}';
    }


    global static void assertEquals(Set<Blob> b1,Set<Blob> b2){ assertEquals(blobToObject(b1),blobToObject(b2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Boolean> b1,Set<Boolean> b2){ assertEquals(booleanToObject(b1),booleanToObject(b2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Date> d1,Set<Date> d2){ assertEquals(dateToObject(d1),dateToObject(d2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Datetime> d1,Set<Datetime> d2){ assertEquals(datetimeToObject(d1),datetimeToObject(d2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Decimal> d1,Set<Decimal> d2){ assertEquals(decimalToObject(d1),decimalToObject(d2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Double> d1,Set<Double> d2){ assertEquals(doubleToObject(d1),doubleToObject(d2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Integer> i1,Set<Integer> i2){ assertEquals(integerToObject(i1),integerToObject(i2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Long> l1,Set<Long> l2){ assertEquals(longToObject(l1),longToObject(l2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<String> s1,Set<String> s2){ assertEquals(stringToObject(s1),stringToObject(s2)); }
    global static void assertEquals(Set<Time> t1,Set<Time> t2){ assertEquals(timeToObject(t1),timeToObject(t2)); }

    global static void assertEquals(Set<Object> expected, Set<Object> actual){
        System.assert(
            equals(expected,actual),
            'Assertion failed, the following two arrays are not equal.  Expected: ' 
                + toString(expected) 
                + ', Actual: ' 
                + toString(actual));
    }

    global static Boolean equals(Set<Blob> b1,Set<Blob> b2){ return equals(blobToObject(b1),blobToObject(b2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Boolean> b1,Set<Boolean> b2){ return equals(booleanToObject(b1),booleanToObject(b2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Date> d1,Set<Date> d2){ return equals(dateToObject(d1),dateToObject(d2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Datetime> d1,Set<Datetime> d2){ return equals(datetimeToObject(d1),datetimeToObject(d2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Decimal> d1,Set<Decimal> d2){ return equals(decimalToObject(d1),decimalToObject(d2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Double> d1,Set<Double> d2){ return equals(doubleToObject(d1),doubleToObject(d2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Integer> i1,Set<Integer> i2){ return equals(integerToObject(i1),integerToObject(i2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Long> l1,Set<Long> l2){ return equals(longToObject(l1),longToObject(l2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<String> s1,Set<String> s2){ return equals(stringToObject(s1),stringToObject(s2)); }
    global static Boolean equals(Set<Time> t1,Set<Time> t2){ return equals(timeToObject(t1),timeToObject(t2)); }

    global static Boolean equals(Set<Object> expected, Set<Object> actual){
        if(expected == null && actual == null){
            return true;
        }
        if((expected == null && actual != null) || (expected != null && actual == null)){
            return false;
        }
        if(expected.size() != actual.size()){
            return false;
        }
        for(Object obj : expected){
            if(!actual.contains(obj)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    global static Set<Object> pluck(List<SObject> records, String fieldName){
        return pluck(listToSet(records),fieldName);
    }   

    global static Set<Object> pluck(Set<SObject> records, String fieldName){
        Set<Object> returnValue = null;
        if(records != null){
            returnValue = new Set<Object>();
            if(records.size() > 0 && StringUtils.isNotBlank(fieldName)){
                for(SObject record : records){
                    returnValue.add(record.get(fieldName));
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static Set<String> pluckString(List<SObject> records, String fieldName){
        return pluckString(listToSet(records),fieldName);
    }

    global static Set<String> pluckString(Set<SObject> records, String fieldName){
        return objectToString(pluck(records,fieldName));
    }

    global static List<String> setToList(Set<String> aSet){
        List<String> returnValue = null;
        if(aSet != null){
            returnValue = new List<String>();
            if(aSet.size() > 0){
                for(String value : aSet){
                    returnValue.add(value);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static List<Object> setToList(Set<Object> records){
        List<Object> returnValue = null;
        if(records != null){
            returnValue = new List<Object>();
            if(records.size() > 0){
                for(Object record : records){
                    returnValue.add(record);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static List<SObject> setToList(Set<SObject> records){
        List<SObject> returnValue = null;
        if(records != null){
            returnValue = new List<SObject>();
            if(records.size() > 0){
                for(SObject record : records){
                    returnValue.add(record);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static Set<String> listToSet(List<String> aList){
        Set<String> returnValue = null;
        if(aList != null){
            returnValue = new Set<String>();
            if(aList.size() > 0){
                for(String value : aList){
                    returnValue.add(value);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static Set<Object> listToSet(List<Object> aList){
        Set<Object> returnValue = null;
        if(aList != null){
            returnValue = new Set<Object>();
            if(aList.size() > 0){
                for(Object value : aList){
                    returnValue.add(value);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static Set<SObject> listToSet(List<SObject> records){
        Set<SObject> returnValue = null;
        if(records != null){
            returnValue = new Set<SObject>();
            if(records.size() > 0){
                for(SObject record : records){
                    returnValue.add(record);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static Set<String> lowerCase(Set<String> strs){
        Set<String> returnValue = null;
        if(strs != null){
            returnValue = new Set<String>();
            if(strs.size() > 0){
                for(String str : strs){
                    returnValue.add(str == null ? null : str.toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static Set<String> upperCase(Set<String> strs){
        Set<String> returnValue = null;
        if(strs != null){
            returnValue = new Set<String>();
            if(strs.size() > 0){
                for(String str : strs){
                    returnValue.add(str == null ? null : str.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    global static Set<String> trim(Set<String> strs){
        Set<String> returnValue = null;
        if(strs != null){
            returnValue = new Set<String>();
            if(strs.size() > 0){
                for(String str : strs){
                    returnValue.add(str == null ? null : str.trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }



}
```

Comment: well I'll be d**ned. I'd been using the sfdcfox version for a while - and apexlang has been around for a while no less.

Comment: @cropredy FYI, apexlang, while rather useful, is outdated, and doesn't take advantage of language features that are now native.